# Control LED using Computer via USB TO IEEE-1284

Tags: c#, usb, controls, led

I have **USB to IEEE-1284**

I want to Control 2 LED using Computer via **USB** to IEEE-1284. I have two on my C# program.

I want to each button lighted each led. First LED is Connected to D0, Second LED is Connected to D1.

Heres My **USB** to IEEE-1284 Pin Configuration:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b75Z5.png

In internet all codes that i found were only controlling real Parallel Port not **USB** to IEEE-1284. I tried using inpout.dll library (i wrote address 1 (I was searching for address in Device Manager But my **USB** IEEE-1284 was showing as USB Printing Support Heres ScreenShot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tvyiilh0fhna2kh/Capture2.PNG) and value 1)

How to fix that?

Comment: These outputs cannot directly drive an LED, they are open collector outputs.  You'll have to bring your own power supply and a current limiting resistor.  Ask questions about this at electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this - with an external controller.

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-control-LEDs-with-Processing-and-Arduino/

Comment: thanks but My question is about Using USB to IEEE-1284 to control LEDS, not Microcontroller

Comment: But that device is not capable of controlling the power to LEDs - it is only capable of sending messages. Something needs to respond to those messages, and loose LEDs aren't smart enough.

Comment: You could turn a transistor on and off with the parallel port signal, yes... but it would blink on and off at a high rate. Maybe an SCR would work. I assume you want to send a message to the parallel port telling it a LED pattern to light up? If you want that pattern to persist for more than a fraction of a second, you'll need a way to control the LEDs from the stored message, otherwise they will blink and turn off again. You can get 5.5V directly from the parallel port, which is enough to light the LED, but it's a short pulse.

Comment: How to send a Message to **USB** to Parallel Port?

Comment: Well that's kinda why your question is being rejected. You need to do the basic research to figure that out yourself. It is way too complicated to explain in a Q&A web site format. And, your multiple posts on the subject are highly likely to poison Google searches for this information. The article I posted has a good starting point though.

Comment: I was Searching it in Google but all what I found was for Real Parallel Port not for **USB** to Parallel Port(IEEE-1284)

Answer (score 0):

This links May be helping you

http://ledthings.com/HowTo/HowToUSB.html

https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~ygu/bastelecke/PC/USB2LPT/index.en.htm

https://superuser.com/questions/182655/how-do-i-simulate-a-parallel-lpt-printer-with-a-usb-printer/493361#493361

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80255/how-to-send-raw-data-to-ieee-1284-parallel-printer-cable/82417#82417

Comment: It's always better to include in your answer more than just links.  SO questions/answers are being viewed long after posting.  So many links do not work by that time.